# Remove Default Read More Link in Manual Excerpt RSS Feed

Tags: excerpt, rss, feed, read-more

I have a site that displays manual excerpts on the blog post page: https://teralynnchilds.com/blog. I added a custom read more link using the snippet found here: https://wpmayor.com/add-read-link-manual-excerpts/

The RSS feed (https://teralynnchilds.com/feed) includes the manual excerpt, the custom read more link, AND a default read more link of "keep reading TITLE at SITE". I am trying to remove that default read more link from the feed but cannot find the source anywhere.

How do I fix it some my feed only includes the manual excerpt and the custom read more link?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default inclusion of "read more" links in WordPress feed descriptions. This is probably being done by your theme or a plugin. You can customize your feed output as explained here:https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

Comment: I was afraid of that. :( Can you recommend a good way to hunt down that piece of code? I installed the String Locator plugin and searched for "keep reading" (without quotes) but the only results are in the cache of my feed.

Comment: It must be getting inserted after or within `the_excerpt` which goes into the RSS `<description>` field and the Atom `<summary>`. This could be happening through a filter in your theme `functions.php` file or a plugin. It could also be happening through feed and/or page templates as described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds. The latter may be more likely if String Locator doesn't look there. Try the "[What the File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/)" too--it may be more helpful for your search.

Comment: I tried What the File, but since the toolbar doesn't show up on the feed page I don't know how to use that for my search... Any other suggestions? (And thank you so much for trying to help!)

Comment:  You're right that's not going to help with the feed page. If you are looking at an archive page that shows the excepts there, it might give you a clue. Did you try looking for feed template files?